# swift navigationControllerのバーの高さ

Tags: swift, ios, uinavigationcontroller, navigationbar

今Swiftを使ってiOSアプリの開発をしているのですが、
NavigationControllerの上のバーの高さが変更できずに困っています。。。。。

方法はないのでしょうか？？

Comment: [Appleのデベロッパーフォーラムに掲載された同類の質問](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/88202#274620)にApple社の方が答えています。_Resizing the navigation bar (via any method, including subclassing) is not supported_ **(メソッドを使おうとサブクラス化しようと)ナビゲーションバーのリサイズはサポートされていません** (まだ続きますが、要はサポートされていないから無理に変なことするとよくない、と言ってます。)「iOS10まではこれで動いたんだけど」とか「実は高さは変えてないけど、特定の状況で似たような効果が得られます」なんて話もあちこちにちらほら見つかりますが、基本は「iOSとしては、それはサポートされていない」と言うことのようです。

Comment: OOPerさん、ありがとうございます！！！